# How do I setup the default version for Gradle and Gradle plugin for Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Every time I create a new project in Android Studio, the default version of Gradle is 2.2.1 and Gradle plug-in is 1.1.0. I know how to update them to the latest (2.3 and 1.1.3) in the build.gradle and gradle-wrapper.properties. However, is there a way I can set it to project default so I don't have to do this every time?

I am using the mac version of android studio 1.2 Beta 2, built on April 7, 2015.

Thanks

Comment: I think that's baked into Android Studio. In theory, it would be available in File > Other Settings > Default Project Structure.